# Template arguments can't be deduced for shared_ptr of class derived from templated base

Tags: c++, templates

I'm running into a case where I thought that the compiler would obviously be able to do template argument deduction, but apparently can't. I'd like to know why I have to give explicit template args in this case. Here's a simplified version of what's going on.

I have an inheritance hierarchy where the base class is templated and derived classes are concrete implementations of the base:

```cpp
template <typename T> class Base {};

class Derived : public Base<int> {};
```

Then I have a templated function which accepts a shared pointer of the base class:

```cpp
template <typename T> void DoSomething(const std::shared_ptr<Base<T>> &ptr);
```

When I try to call this method, I have to explicitly provide the template arguments:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Derived> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
DoSomething(d);      // doesn't compile!
DoSomething<int>(d); // works just fine
```

In particular, I get this error message if I don't use explicit template arguments:

```
main.cpp:23:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘DoSomething(std::shared_ptr&)’
   23 |     DoSomething(d);
      |                  ^
main.cpp:10:28: note: candidate: ‘template void DoSomething(const std::shared_ptr >&)’
   10 | template <typename T> void DoSomething(const shared_ptr<Base<T>> &ptr)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:23:18: note:   mismatched types ‘Base’ and ‘Derived’
   23 |     DoSomething(d);
      |                  ^
```

What's even more confusing to me is that template arguments *can* be deduced if I don't use `shared_ptr`:

```cpp
template <typename T> void DoSomethingElse(const Base<T> &b);

Derived d;
DoSomethingElse(d); // doesn't need explicit template args!
```

So obviously I need to specify the template arguments for `DoSomething`. But my question is, why? Why can't the compiler deduce the template in this case? `Derived` implements `Base<int>` and the type can be deduced in `DoSomethingElse`, so why does sticking it in a `shared_ptr` change the compiler's ability to figure out that `T` should be `int`?

---

Full example code which reproduces the issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T> class Base {};

class Derived : public Base<int> {};

template <typename T> void DoSomething(const std::shared_ptr<Base<T>> &ptr)
{
    std::cout << "doing something" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> void DoSomethingElse(const Base<T> &b)
{
    std::cout << "doing something else" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    // DoSomething(d);   // doesn't compile!
    DoSomething<int>(d); // works just fine
    
    Derived d2;
    DoSomethingElse(d2); // doesn't need explicit template args!
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Derived` is a derived class of `Base<int>`, but `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` isn't a derived class of `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>`.

So if you have a function of the form

```
template <typename T> void f(const Base<T>&);
```

and you pass a `Derived` value to it, the compiler will first notice that it can't match up `Base<T>` against `Derived`, and then try to match up `Base<T>` against a base class of `Derived`. This then succeeds since `Base<int>` is one of the base classes.

If you have a function of the form

```
template <typename T> void f(const std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>&);
```

and you pass a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`, then the compiler will fail to match that against `std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>` and then try with base classes of `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`. If the latter has any base classes at all, they are internal to the standard library, and *not* related to `std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>`, so deduction ultimately fails.

What you are asking the compiler to do here is to say: "aha! `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` can be *converted* into `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>`, which matches the function parameter!" But the compiler won't do that, because in general, there is no algorithm that the compiler can use in order to make a list of all types that a given type can be converted to.

Instead, you must help the compiler by telling it explicitly what to convert to. This can be done like so:

```
template <typename T>
Base<T> get_base(const Base<T>*);  // doesn't need definition

template <typename T> void DoSomething(const std::shared_ptr<Base<T>> &ptr);

template <typename D, typename B = decltype(get_base((D*)nullptr))>
void DoSomething(const std::shared_ptr<D>& ptr) {
    DoSomething(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<B>>(ptr));
}
```

Here, when the second `DoSomething` overload is called with an argument of type `std::shared_ptr<D>`, the `get_base` helper function will be used to determine the base class of `D` itself that has the form `Base<T>`. Then, the `std::shared_ptr<D>` will be explicitly converted to `std::shared_ptr<Base<T>>` so that the first overload can be called. Finally, note that if `D` isn't  a derived class of any `Base<T>`, the second overload  will be removed from the overload set, potentially enabling some other overload to handle the argument type.

Comment: It makes sense that `shared_ptr<Derived>` is not derived from `shared_ptr<Base<int>>`. However, I'm still confused because this argument doesn't seem to track when you remove templating. If I change my example to remove all of the templating I can pass a `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `DoSomething(shared_ptr<Base>)` just fine, and it's able to convert from `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>` (working example here: https://pastebin.com/mcd9JJNL). So why does this break down when we introduce templating?

Comment: @wlyles If there are no templates involved, the compiler simply tries to convert the type of the argument to the type of the parameter. If there are templates involved, then there are infinitely many possible template parameter types since it depends on the template parameter, so the compiler doesn't know what to try. In this case it so happens that there is a `T` such that the conversion is possible, but there is no algorithm that lets the compiler figure that out.

Comment: Ah I see. So the non-templated version works because the conversion is well defined, but in the templated case it's not. I think what happened then is that I interpreted the non-templated case to imply that templates (or at least the `shared_ptr` template) were covariant when in fact it's actually a conversion that's happening implicitly. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: @wlyles I'm not really sure what you mean by "covariant"; if you mean that you assumed there to be an inheritance relationship, then yes, that assumption does not hold, as I previously said.